# Small ES cluster stuck on initializing_shards

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I have a 2.4.4 cluster with a single server/node (esnode1) containing only one 220GB index with 1 shard and zero replicas.

The index was responding fine, but whenever I cleanly restart the server (ec2 with 2cpu 4GB RAM 500GB SSD) the cluster state gets stuck on red with "initializing_shards" = 1, but no CPU or disk usage (the system is idle and not swapping) for quite a while.

I've already raised indices.recovery.max_bytes_per_sec to 50mb, and tried the instructions at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_rolling_restarts.html, without success.

This only occurs if I set a 2GB heap for ES. However, with a 3GB heap the cluster status changes to green seconds after restart.

I'm at a loss as to how to debug or understand this, as the logs (below) seem pretty much normal, any hints?

/cluster/_health is

```
 {
      "cluster_name" : "escluster1",
      "status" : "red",
      "timed_out" : false,
      "number_of_nodes" : 1,
      "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
      "active_primary_shards" : 0,
      "active_shards" : 0,
      "relocating_shards" : 0,
      "initializing_shards" : 1,
      "unassigned_shards" : 0,
      "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
      "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
      "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
      "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
      "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 0.0
    }
```

This is the log following a restart:

```
[2017-05-04 15:00:37,975][INFO ][node                     ] [esnode1] version[2.4.4], pid[2761], build[fcbb46d/2017-01-03T11:33:16Z]
[2017-05-04 15:00:37,976][INFO ][node                     ] [esnode1] initializing ...
[2017-05-04 15:00:38,534][INFO ][plugins                  ] [esnode1] modules [reindex, lang-expression, lang-groovy], plugins [], sites []
[2017-05-04 15:00:38,563][INFO ][env                      ] [esnode1] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/mnt/esdata2 (/dev/xvdh1)]], net usable_space [226.3gb], net total_space [492gb], spins? [no], types [ext4]
[2017-05-04 15:00:38,563][INFO ][env                      ] [esnode1] heap size [1.9gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2017-05-04 15:00:40,379][INFO ][node                     ] [esnode1] initialized
[2017-05-04 15:00:40,380][INFO ][node                     ] [esnode1] starting ...
[2017-05-04 15:00:40,501][INFO ][transport                ] [esnode1] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9300}, bound_addresses {[::1]:9300}, {127.0.0.1:9300}
[2017-05-04 15:00:40,506][INFO ][discovery                ] [esnode1] escluster1/sv3aHhUjSyueq5N4_w14mQ
[2017-05-04 15:00:43,565][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [esnode1] new_master {esnode1}{sv3aHhUjSyueq5N4_w14mQ}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}, reason: zen-disco-join(elected_as_master, [0] joins received)
[2017-05-04 15:00:43,595][INFO ][indices.recovery         ] [esnode1] updating [indices.recovery.max_bytes_per_sec] from [40mb] to [50mb]
[2017-05-04 15:00:43,631][INFO ][http                     ] [esnode1] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9200}, bound_addresses {[::1]:9200}, {127.0.0.1:9200}
[2017-05-04 15:00:43,632][INFO ][node                     ] [esnode1] started
[2017-05-04 15:00:43,651][INFO ][gateway                  ] [esnode1] recovered
```

**Edit 1**: switching the log level to DEBUG, with a 2GB heap, the cluster state remains "red" and I can see the following message being logged repeatedly every 30 seconds:

```
[2017-05-10 15:58:45,985][DEBUG][index.shard              ] [esnode1] [myIndex][0] updateBufferSize: engine is closed; skipping
[2017-05-10 15:59:15,985][DEBUG][indices.memory           ] [esnode1] recalculating shard indexing buffer, total is [203.1mb] with [1] active shards, each shard set to indexing=[203.1mb], translog=[64kb]
[2017-05-10 15:59:15,990][DEBUG][index.shard              ] [esnode1] [myIndex][0] updateBufferSize: engine is closed; skipping
[2017-05-10 15:59:45,990][DEBUG][indices.memory           ] [esnode1] recalculating shard indexing buffer, total is [203.1mb] with [1] active shards, each shard set to indexing=[203.1mb], translog=[64kb]
[2017-05-10 15:59:45,997][DEBUG][index.shard              ] [esnode1] [myIndex][0] updateBufferSize: engine is closed; skipping
[2017-05-10 16:00:15,997][DEBUG][indices.memory           ] [esnode1] recalculating shard indexing buffer, total is [203.1mb] with [1] active shards, each shard set to indexing=[203.1mb], translog=[64kb]
```

**Edit 2**: outputs produced  with a 3GB heap and "green" status:

_nodes/stats?filter_path=**.indices.segments :

```
{
  "nodes" : {
    "TeXgE1QKSMOE1xYS-miJug" : {
      "indices" : {
        "segments" : {
          "count" : 73,
          "memory_in_bytes" : 2272548617,
          "terms_memory_in_bytes" : 2269433701,
          "stored_fields_memory_in_bytes" : 3103096,
          "term_vectors_memory_in_bytes" : 0,
          "norms_memory_in_bytes" : 4672,
          "doc_values_memory_in_bytes" : 7148,
          "index_writer_memory_in_bytes" : 0,
          "index_writer_max_memory_in_bytes" : 320379289,
          "version_map_memory_in_bytes" : 0,
          "fixed_bit_set_memory_in_bytes" : 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

/_nodes/stats/jvm?filter_path=**.heap_used_in_bytes

```
{
  "cluster_name" : "escluster1",
  "nodes" : {
    "TeXgE1QKSMOE1xYS-miJug" : {
      "timestamp" : 1494501231058,
      "name" : "esnode1",
      "transport_address" : "127.0.0.1:9300",
      "host" : "127.0.0.1",
      "ip" : [ "127.0.0.1:9300", "NONE" ],
      "indices" : {
        "docs" : {
          "count" : 5352169,
          "deleted" : 0
        },
        "store" : {
          "size_in_bytes" : 234847391460,
          "throttle_time_in_millis" : 0
        },
        "indexing" : {
          "index_total" : 0,
          "index_time_in_millis" : 0,
          "index_current" : 0,
          "index_failed" : 0,
          "delete_total" : 0,
          "delete_time_in_millis" : 0,
          "delete_current" : 0,
          "noop_update_total" : 0,
          "is_throttled" : false,
          "throttle_time_in_millis" : 0
        },
        "get" : {
          "total" : 0,
          "time_in_millis" : 0,
          "exists_total" : 0,
          "exists_time_in_millis" : 0,
          "missing_total" : 0,
          "missing_time_in_millis" : 0,
          "current" : 0
        },
        "search" : {
          "open_contexts" : 0,
          "query_total" : 0,
          "query_time_in_millis" : 0,
          "query_current" : 0,
          "fetch_total" : 0,
          "fetch_time_in_millis" : 0,
          "fetch_current" : 0,
          "scroll_total" : 0,
          "scroll_time_in_millis" : 0,
          "scroll_current" : 0
        },
        "merges" : {
          "current" : 0,
          "current_docs" : 0,
          "current_size_in_bytes" : 0,
          "total" : 0,
          "total_time_in_millis" : 0,
          "total_docs" : 0,
          "total_size_in_bytes" : 0,
          "total_stopped_time_in_millis" : 0,
          "total_throttled_time_in_millis" : 0,
          "total_auto_throttle_in_bytes" : 20971520
        },
        "refresh" : {
          "total" : 1,
          "total_time_in_millis" : 14
        },
        "flush" : {
          "total" : 1,
          "total_time_in_millis" : 10
        },
        "warmer" : {
          "current" : 0,
          "total" : 3,
          "total_time_in_millis" : 6
        },
        "query_cache" : {
          "memory_size_in_bytes" : 0,
          "total_count" : 0,
          "hit_count" : 0,
          "miss_count" : 0,
          "cache_size" : 0,
          "cache_count" : 0,
          "evictions" : 0
        },
        "fielddata" : {
          "memory_size_in_bytes" : 0,
          "evictions" : 0
        },
        "percolate" : {
          "total" : 0,
          "time_in_millis" : 0,
          "current" : 0,
          "memory_size_in_bytes" : -1,
          "memory_size" : "-1b",
          "queries" : 0
        },
        "completion" : {
          "size_in_bytes" : 0
        },
        "segments" : {
          "count" : 73,
          "memory_in_bytes" : 2272548617,
          "terms_memory_in_bytes" : 2269433701,
          "stored_fields_memory_in_bytes" : 3103096,
          "term_vectors_memory_in_bytes" : 0,
          "norms_memory_in_bytes" : 4672,
          "doc_values_memory_in_bytes" : 7148,
          "index_writer_memory_in_bytes" : 0,
          "index_writer_max_memory_in_bytes" : 512000,
          "version_map_memory_in_bytes" : 0,
          "fixed_bit_set_memory_in_bytes" : 0
        },
        "translog" : {
          "operations" : 0,
          "size_in_bytes" : 43
        },
        "suggest" : {
          "total" : 0,
          "time_in_millis" : 0,
          "current" : 0
        },
        "request_cache" : {
          "memory_size_in_bytes" : 0,
          "evictions" : 0,
          "hit_count" : 0,
          "miss_count" : 0
        },
        "recovery" : {
          "current_as_source" : 0,
          "current_as_target" : 0,
          "throttle_time_in_millis" : 0
        }
      },
      "os" : {
        "timestamp" : 1494501231060,
        "cpu_percent" : 0,
        "load_average" : 0.0,
        "mem" : {
          "total_in_bytes" : 4142092288,
          "free_in_bytes" : 117051392,
          "used_in_bytes" : 4025040896,
          "free_percent" : 3,
          "used_percent" : 97
        },
        "swap" : {
          "total_in_bytes" : 0,
          "free_in_bytes" : 0,
          "used_in_bytes" : 0
        }
      },
      "process" : {
        "timestamp" : 1494501231060,
        "open_file_descriptors" : 203,
        "max_file_descriptors" : 65536,
        "cpu" : {
          "percent" : 0,
          "total_in_millis" : 14890
        },
        "mem" : {
          "total_virtual_in_bytes" : 23821713408
        }
      },
      "jvm" : {
        "timestamp" : 1494501231060,
        "uptime_in_millis" : 369041,
        "mem" : {
          "heap_used_in_bytes" : 2323777096,
          "heap_used_percent" : 72,
          "heap_committed_in_bytes" : 3203792896,
          "heap_max_in_bytes" : 3203792896,
          "non_heap_used_in_bytes" : 52525744,
          "non_heap_committed_in_bytes" : 53305344,
          "pools" : {
            "young" : {
              "used_in_bytes" : 121416432,
              "max_in_bytes" : 139591680,
              "peak_used_in_bytes" : 139591680,
              "peak_max_in_bytes" : 139591680
            },
            "survivor" : {
              "used_in_bytes" : 4653304,
              "max_in_bytes" : 17432576,
              "peak_used_in_bytes" : 17432576,
              "peak_max_in_bytes" : 17432576
            },
            "old" : {
              "used_in_bytes" : 2197707360,
              "max_in_bytes" : 3046768640,
              "peak_used_in_bytes" : 2197707360,
              "peak_max_in_bytes" : 3046768640
            }
          }
        },
        "threads" : {
          "count" : 34,
          "peak_count" : 42
        },
        "gc" : {
          "collectors" : {
            "young" : {
              "collection_count" : 23,
              "collection_time_in_millis" : 1027
            },
            "old" : {
              "collection_count" : 1,
              "collection_time_in_millis" : 26
            }
          }
        },
        "buffer_pools" : {
          "direct" : {
            "count" : 24,
            "used_in_bytes" : 3964472,
            "total_capacity_in_bytes" : 3964472
          },
          "mapped" : {
            "count" : 33,
            "used_in_bytes" : 18005744733,
            "total_capacity_in_bytes" : 18005744733
          }
        },
        "classes" : {
          "current_loaded_count" : 7490,
          "total_loaded_count" : 7490,
          "total_unloaded_count" : 0
        }
      },
      "thread_pool" : {
        "bulk" : {
          "threads" : 0,
          "queue" : 0,
          "active" : 0,
          "rejected" : 0,
          "largest" : 0,
          "completed" : 0
        },
        "fetch_shard_started" : {
          "threads" : 1,
          "queue" : 0,
          "active" : 0,
          "rejected" : 0,
          "largest" : 1,
          "completed" : 1
        },
        "fetch_shard_store" : {
          "threads" : 0,
          "queue" : 0,
          "active" : 0,
          "rejected" : 0,
          "largest" : 0,
          "completed" : 0
        },
        "flush" : {
          "threads" : 1,
          "queue" : 0,
          "active" : 0,
          "rejected" : 0,
          "largest" : 1,
          "completed" : 2
        },
        "force_merge" : {
          "threads" : 0,
          "queue" : 0,
          "active" : 0,
          "rejected" : 0,
          "largest" : 0,
          "completed" : 0
        },
        "generic" : {
          "threads" : 1,
          "queue" : 0,
          "active" : 0,
          "rejected" : 0,
          "largest" : 5,
          "completed" : 69
        },
        "get" : {
          "threads" : 0,
          "queue" : 0,
          "active" : 0,
          "rejected" : 0,
          "largest" : 0,
          "completed" : 0
        },
        "index" : {
          "threads" : 0,
          "queue" : 0,
          "active" : 0,
          "rejected" : 0,
          "largest" : 0,
          "completed" : 0
        },
        "listener" : {
          "threads" : 1,
          "queue" : 0,
          "active" : 0,
          "rejected" : 0,
          "largest" : 1,
          "completed" : 2
        },
        "management" : {
          "threads" : 3,
          "queue" : 0,
          "active" : 1,
          "rejected" : 0,
          "largest" : 3,
          "completed" : 41
        },
        "percolate" : {
          "threads" : 0,
          "queue" : 0,
          "active" : 0,
          "rejected" : 0,
          "largest" : 0,
          "completed" : 0
        },
        "refresh" : {
          "threads" : 1,
          "queue" : 0,
          "active" : 0,
          "rejected" : 0,
          "largest" : 1,
          "completed" : 1
        },
        "search" : {
          "threads" : 0,
          "queue" : 0,
          "active" : 0,
          "rejected" : 0,
          "largest" : 0,
          "completed" : 0
        },
        "snapshot" : {
          "threads" : 0,
          "queue" : 0,
          "active" : 0,
          "rejected" : 0,
          "largest" : 0,
          "completed" : 0
        },
        "suggest" : {
          "threads" : 0,
          "queue" : 0,
          "active" : 0,
          "rejected" : 0,
          "largest" : 0,
          "completed" : 0
        },
        "warmer" : {
          "threads" : 1,
          "queue" : 0,
          "active" : 0,
          "rejected" : 0,
          "largest" : 1,
          "completed" : 1
        }
      },
      "fs" : {
        "timestamp" : 1494501231060,
        "total" : {
          "total_in_bytes" : 528311836672,
          "free_in_bytes" : 249557147648,
          "available_in_bytes" : 222696878080
        },
        "data" : [ {
          "path" : "/mnt/esdata2/data/escluster1/nodes/0",
          "mount" : "/mnt/esdata2 (/dev/xvdh1)",
          "type" : "ext4",
          "total_in_bytes" : 528311836672,
          "free_in_bytes" : 249557147648,
          "available_in_bytes" : 222696878080,
          "spins" : "false"
        } ]
      },
      "transport" : {
        "server_open" : 0,
        "rx_count" : 6,
        "rx_size_in_bytes" : 2352,
        "tx_count" : 6,
        "tx_size_in_bytes" : 2352
      },
      "http" : {
        "current_open" : 1,
        "total_opened" : 6
      },
      "breakers" : {
        "request" : {
          "limit_size_in_bytes" : 1281517158,
          "limit_size" : "1.1gb",
          "estimated_size_in_bytes" : 0,
          "estimated_size" : "0b",
          "overhead" : 1.0,
          "tripped" : 0
        },
        "fielddata" : {
          "limit_size_in_bytes" : 1922275737,
          "limit_size" : "1.7gb",
          "estimated_size_in_bytes" : 0,
          "estimated_size" : "0b",
          "overhead" : 1.03,
          "tripped" : 0
        },
        "in_flight_requests" : {
          "limit_size_in_bytes" : 3203792896,
          "limit_size" : "2.9gb",
          "estimated_size_in_bytes" : 0,
          "estimated_size" : "0b",
          "overhead" : 1.0,
          "tripped" : 0
        },
        "parent" : {
          "limit_size_in_bytes" : 2242655027,
          "limit_size" : "2gb",
          "estimated_size_in_bytes" : 0,
          "estimated_size" : "0b",
          "overhead" : 1.0,
          "tripped" : 0
        }
      },
      "script" : {
        "compilations" : 0,
        "cache_evictions" : 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's probably a simple answer: A 220GB is not a small index for a 2GB heap size ;-). And it's hard to believe the CPU is not doing anything... I'm expecting the JVM to run GCs almost constantly (if the memory was not enough for the index).

Comment: Ypiu might want to switch the logs to debug first:  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/logging.html

Comment: @AndreiStefan, that had occured to me, but a 3GB heap works fine for that 220GB index, and I would expect to see something related to low memory reported in the logs (will try changing the log level as suggested, but IMO and OutOfMemoryException shouldn't really be a debug message, it seems like a critical issue that should always be logged)

Comment: @asettouf post edited after switching logging levelto DEBUG, thanks

Comment: @derelict with a 3GB heap, after the node starts up and is fine, run these two commands and provide the output: `GET /_nodes/stats?filter_path=**.indices.segments` and `GET /_nodes/stats/jvm?filter_path=**.heap_used_in_bytes`

Comment: @AndreiStefan, I edited the post to include the info you asked for, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `segments` kind-of static data (meaning the terms, inverted index etc) that is associated with your data only, is pretty big - `"memory_in_bytes" : 2272548617` which is 2.11 GB.

And that's the reason why your ES node is not able to do anything when you give it 2GB heap.

Apart from the 2.11 GB static data, while indexing, searching there is more memory required of course. So your node needs to have at least 3GB heap and at least 6GB RAM.

Comment: That makes sense. Indexing this data successfully required a 4CPU 16GB RAM 10GB heap server, though searches (it's a read only index) are actually pretty quick using a 3GB heap. I would expect a basic log message like "not enough heap memory for segments", though, otherwise this is hard to debug and come to definitive conclusions...

Comment: Should a _forcemerge help here? I believe the docs mentioned the ideal # of segments = 1, especially given that this index is only written to by a batch process. _all is disabled and only two fields are indexed as analyzed strings.

Comment: What's the full mapping and settings of this index?

Comment: Edited the answer with the mappings and settings, tks

Comment: The mapping is looking good, you don't have that many segments. All in all, I don't think it will help a _force_merge so much that a 2GB heap will be ok. I really don't think so.

Comment: So, ideally the heap will have to be large enough to contain at least the amount of "memory_in_bytes" for all indexes in the cluster, is that correct? Are there any info/docs that you'd recommend in order to understand these sizing issues other than the basic docs on elastic.co? Thanks.

Comment: Not that I know of. But the nodes' stats commands that I asked you to provide should be a good resource for evaluating the memory usage.

Comment: Yes, my question was if you knew of any kind of reference that would provide insights on the several settings/stats that are listed by that command.

Comment: what's in the docs is all there is: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/cluster-nodes-stats.html